# How to change colors to lightning:buttonStateful component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I want to implement a button with states - `lightning:buttonStateful` seems to be the right standard component for that.

The problem is - I want to put a few buttons - more than 5 and to have for each button a different color.

[lightning:buttonStateful](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_buttonStateful.htm) has the `variant` attribute which change colors, but it has only 3!

So I want to know is there a way to change the button colors?

I have tried to put a css class and change the background color, but the button has 2 different states - selected, unselected and hover, and I want to change all states.

**component markup**

```
<aura:attribute name="buttonstate" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
<lightning:buttonStateful
    labelWhenOff="Follow"
    labelWhenOn="Following"
    labelWhenHover="Unfollow"
    iconNameWhenOff="utility:add"
    iconNameWhenOn="utility:check"
    iconNameWhenHover="utility:close"
    variant="success"
    state="{! v.buttonstate }"
    onclick="{! c.handleClick }"
    class="ColorBlue"
/>
```

**component css**

```
.THIS .ColorBlue {
    background-color: rgb(0, 95, 178);
}
```

Comment: Depending on where your button is located, you may have meant `.THIS.ColorBlue` instead of `.THIS .ColorBlue` (note the space). As @Basti said, you may also need `:active` and `:hover` for a complete make-over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `:active` and `:hover` [css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp) I guess:

```
.THIS .ColorBlue,
.THIS .ColorBlue:active,
.THIS .ColorBlue:hover {
    background-color: rgb(0, 95, 178);
}
```

**EDIT**

This is the final answer that works great:

```
.THIS.ColorBlue,
.THIS.ColorBlue:active,
.THIS.ColorBlue:hover {
    background-color: rgb(0, 95, 178) !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Basti and @sfdcfox, your combined solution was almost perfect - eventually, I have also added !important to my css class because a transparency overrided by css background color, so Basti - I am editing your solution so it would be the right one

Comment: sure, feel free, glad we could help :)